# Function returning array

Tags: vba, excel, type-mismatch

I want to separate string after word "and". I use to do this, I write below function

```
Public Function find(separate_text) As Variant
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim text As String
 text = CStr(separate_text)
 ReDim returned(InStr(text, "and") To Len(CStr(text))) As Variant

 For i = InStr(CStr(text), "and") To Len(CStr(text)) - 4
     returned(i) = Mid(text, i + 4, 1)
 Next i
 find = returned
End Function
```

When I want call it:

```
MsgBox CStr(find(example))
```

It's cause 13 error (mismatch). Where's the problem?

Comment: Why do you need to return an array?  Do you just want the string after "and"? You've not declared `returned`, so you can't ReDim it, and you're returning `find_attacks` instead of `find`.

Comment: Add `option explicit` to your code so you can identify the majority of your problems.

Comment: @Tim you *can* ReDim an undeclared variable even with `Option Explicit`. Otherwise spot on. Use of option explicit would've alerted OP to potential discrepancy assigning the return value to `find_atacks` rather than `find`. However I would still expect an error since `returned` is a variant array which cannot be coerced to a string.

Comment: @DavidZemens - yes, of course. I should always test my assumptions.

Comment: If the `find()` does return Array, Kulis can do `MsgBox Join(find(example),vbCrLf))` - Each element in array on a separate line in the msgbox.

Comment: @TimWilliams This mistake (of course must be a find). Yes, I want string after "and".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. if you want the first part of the separate_text to be returned, return splittext(0) in the third line

```
Public Function MyFind(separate_text As String) As String

splittext = Split(separate_text, "and")

MyFind = LTrim(splittext(1))

End Function
```

Comment: If the string don't contain "and", it cause error. How to change this code to prevent for this?

Comment: Read up on Split function. You need a marker to tell the split function where to split the string. In the above example "and" is that marker. You can replace it with anything else you want. It will obviously not work if the string does not have "and".

Comment: I solve this problem using: `If InStr(separate_text, "and") > 1 Then`